# Make Flutter files colored in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, flutter-file

This is the view of my files in Visual Studio Code.

[image: My files]

And his how I'd like my files to be displayed.

[image: How I want them]

How can I colorize my files in this way for easy reading?

Answer (score 4):

This is the extension [Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme). If you install it, you should see something similar to your second picture in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

The extension you are searching for it's on Visual Studio Code.
It's called **vscode-icons**.

[Link on the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)

How to install:

> Open VSCode > File > Preferences > Extensions > Search "vscode-icons"

> Click install and restart VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Download your icon theme

[Nomo Dark Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-icontheme-nomo-dark)

OR

[Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme)

You can choose your favorite extension by trying

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio you can use **Atom Material Icons**

[image]

For VS Code I am using extension named **vscode-icons**